# Why do i get a wrong barcode for my EAN using ZPL

Tags: barcode, zpl

i have a question regarding printing EAN Barcodes with ZPL.
Why do the Barcode and my given EAN dont match?

I have following ZPL code to generate the Barcode.

```
^XA^PQ1,0,0,N^FO50,20^BY^BEN,140,Y,N^FD4250164837159^FS^XZ
```

The result of this is following:

[image]

Can please someone help me with this. I am close to giving up on this.

Thank you!

Faby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure calling '^BY' with no values is doing any good, and '^PQ' is set to the default values making it redundant.  But regardless, you're passing too many digits in '^FD'.  Zebra wants to add it's own checksum:

```
Field data ( ^FD ) is limited to exactly 12 characters. ZPL II
automatically truncates or pads on the left with zeros to achieve the 
required number of characters
```

See p101 of the Zebra Programming Guide for details.  If you need to encode the 9 (which is not the correct checksum) then you should look at EAN14(or GTIN14).

Comment: Certainly. The correct checksum digit for article `425016483715` is `8` as calculated by the firmware, not `9`

Comment: Yeah i think thats really what throws off the whole calculation. We got the Article with this EAN and just wanted to add it to our Database. I guess the Manufacturer made a mistake with the Checksum.
Thank you both for your response!